# Showing output from two different class/XML file in one view

Tags: android

How to display output in emulator in one view from two different class and XML file. I want top half to show output from one class and bottom half to show output from the other class. Is this possible? If yes, how?

Comment: You should have a single activity class with a single layout.xml file, in which you can inflate the two 'separate' views one below the other, and interact with them.

Answer (score 0):

That is possible in 3.0...with the use of fragment tag.

for further detail of that... 
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/02/android-30-fragments-api.html